# Why is the label color not turning green when the radio is checked?

Tags: html, css, forms, input, label

I'm having some problems with changing the color of the label when the radio input is checked.

When I use this:

```
input:checked + label {
color: green}
```

Then normally it works, but not on this little project.

Can someone please explain it to me why it is not working. I think it has something to do with the usage of SASS. It always works when I'm using plain CSS.

Github repository: https://github.com/Nova988/Tip-calculator-App

Netlify Site: https://priceless-hodgkin-c38abb.netlify.app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the HTML.

The label comes before the input radio button - which you can also see just looking at the page - the circle (radio button) is after the % label.

Your CSS relies on the label coming after the input.

Comment: Love you. Stupid on my part, but I wont make the same mistake again haha.

Comment: Just curious: is there a way to make it work by changing the css and not the html?

Comment: Not that I can think of. It is sometimes possible to style an element that comes before another one for background color - by adding a pseudo element to the 'another one' but we aren't allowed to attach a pseudo element to an input so that won't work here.